# Bash extract after substring and before substring

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep, expression

Say I have a string:

```
random text before authentication_token = 'pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ', gravatar_hash = 'd74a97f
```

I want a shell command to extract everything after `"authentication_token = '"` and before the next `'`.

So basically, I want to return `pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
text="random text before authentication_token = 'pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ', gravatar_hash = 'd74a97f"
token=${text##* authentication_token = \'}   # Remove the left part.
token=${token%%\'*}                          # Remove the right part.
echo "$token"
```

Note that it works even if random text contains `authentication token = '...'`.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest answer since it doesn't call any external programs. Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your grep supports `-P` then you could use this PCRE regex,

```
$ echo "random text before authentication_token = 'pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ', gravatar_hash = 'd74a97f" | grep -oP "authentication_token = '\K[^']*"
pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ

$ echo "random text before authentication_token = 'pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ', gravatar_hash = 'd74a97f" | grep -oP "authentication_token = '\K[^']*(?=')"
pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ
```

- `\K` discards previously matched characters from printing at the final.
- `[^']*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `'` zero or more times.
- `(?=')` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a single quote.

Comment: In your 2nd example, did you mean to write `.*?(?=')` ? Otherwise the example adds nothing to the 1st one.

Comment: @glenn no, the first one works for this input only, it won't check for the following `'` at the end. So this would match also match strings which don't have any ending single quote. But the positive lookahead at the second one asserts that the match must be followed by a single quote. So this only match the string which has opening aswell as closing single quote.

Answer (score 2):

My simple version is

```
sed -r "s/(.*authentication_token = ')([^']*)(.*)/\2/"
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, `grep -oP` is the best solution. For completeness, a couple of alternatives:

```
sed 's/.*authentication_token = '\''//; s/'\''.*//' <<<"$string"
```

```
awk -F "'" '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) if ($1 ~ /authentication_token = $/) {print $(i+1); break}}' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bash`'s regular expression matching facilities.

```
$ regex="_token = '([^']+)'"
$ string="random text before authentication_token = 'pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ', gravatar_hash = 'd74a97f'"
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && hash=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo "$hash"
pYWastSemJrMqwJycZPZ
```

Using a variable in place of a literal regular expression simplifies quoting the spaces and single quotes.